# Peterson's Algorithm on C++ multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've written a simple implementation for Peterson's Algorithm in C++ with multi threading. This program changes the string through two threads. But I'm not getting the final result. Where am I wrong?

```
using namespace std;

int flag[2]={0,1};
int turn;

void* first(void* data){
    flag[0]=1;
    turn=1;
    while(flag[1] && turn==1){}
    string &str=*(static_cast<string*>(data));
    if(str!=""){
        if(str=="abcd"){
            str="Hello";
        }
    }
    flag[0]=0;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* second(void* data){
    flag[1]=1;
    turn=0;
    while(flag[0] && turn==0){}
    string &str=*(static_cast<string*>(data));
    if(str!=""){
        if(str=="wxyz"){
            str="abcd";
        }
    }
    flag[1]=0;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    int rc=0;
    string s = "wxyz";
    pthread_t t;

    rc=pthread_create(&t,NULL,first,static_cast<void*>(&s));
    if(rc!=0){
        cout<<"error!";
        exit(rc);
    }
    rc=pthread_create(&t,NULL,second,static_cast<void*>(&s));
    if(rc!=0){
        cout<<"error!";
        exit(rc);
    }

    while(flag[0] && flag[1]!=0){}
    cout<<s;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make the threads wait till the thread `first` has finished, so I created separate threads, `t` for `first` and `u` for `second` and make `main` wait by `pthread_join` till the threads have finished. This removed the need to `main` spin.

Changes:

```
pthread_t t,u;
pthread_create(&t,NULL,first,static_cast<void*>(&s));
pthread_create(&u,NULL,second,static_cast<void*>(&s));
pthread_join(u,NULL);
pthread_join(t,NULL);
//while(flag[0] && flag[1]!=0){}
cout<<s;
```

The atomic fence in functions remained as they ensured ordered execution of instructions.

```
OUTPUT
abcd
```

and

```
Hello
```

And although changing the order of `pthread_create`of `first` and `second` always outputs to `Hello`, It kills the very idea of first thread waiting for second thread to complete. So I think the above changes will be the answer to it.

Comment: `flag[0]=1; turn=1; while(flag[1] && turn==1){}` -- this is not an atomic fence in C++.  This is a race condition and your code executes undefined behavior under the C++11 standard.  Practically, compilers in C++11 are free to assume that unsynchronized access to global data is race-condition free and loads can be cached.  Your code needs fences and/or atomics and/or mutexes to be legal C++11 code.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to C++11 there was no threading model in C++.  After C++11, your code does unordered access to the same variable causing race conditions.

Race conditions result in undefined behavior.

Changing a `std::string` is not atomic.  You cannot do it safely while other threads are reading or writing from it.

In C++11 the threading primitives of `std` are a better idea than the above raw pthread code, excluding the very rare features you cannot emulate.

Comment: @Adnan yes, but also you need to make `flag` and `turn` std::atomic types - plus synchronise access to the string with a mutex. If you don't do this, one thread will not 'see' the changes made by the other in the correct order (or at all).

Comment: I already included Peterson's algorithm to mutually exclude string access, but did not make `flag` and `turn` atomic. I will also convert string assignment to atomic (if that can be possible), and post the results

Answer (score 0):

Refactored to use atomics. Note the explicit fences to guarantee correct ordering or reads/writes to the (non-atomic) string across threads.

Maybe someone would like to sanity-check my logic?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

// atomic types require the compiler to issue appropriate
// store-release/load-acquire ordering
std::atomic<int> flag[2]={{0},{1}};
std::atomic<int> turn;


void first(std::string& str){
    flag[0]=1;
    turn=1;
    while(flag[1] && turn==1){}
    std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if(str!=""){
        if(str=="abcd"){
            str="Hello";
            std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }
    flag[0]=0;
}

void second(std::string& str){
    flag[1]=1;
    turn=0;
    while(flag[0] && turn==0){}
    std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if(str!=""){
        if(str=="wxyz"){
            str="abcd";
            std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }
    flag[1]=0;
}

int main(){
    string s = "wxyz";

    auto t1 = std::thread(first, std::ref(s));
    auto t2 = std::thread(second, std::ref(s));

    for( ; flag[0] && flag[1]; )
        ;

    std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    cout << s << endl;

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
wxyz
```

Endnote:

Modern memory architectures are not what they were when this algorithm was invented. Reads and writes to memory don't happen when you expect on a modern chip, and sometimes don't happen at all.

Cancel your appointments for the next 3 hours and watch this fantastic talk on the subject:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2

Comment: remove the `=` sign on atomic `flag` declaration. Tried it, and got output as `abcd` and `wxyz`. Even the memory fencing cannot create the desired result. I'll let some more suggestions to come on it, maybe some correction on fencing

Comment: I do not understand why `"abcd"` is not a reasonably expected result.  There is next to no sync with the main thread?  If neither thread starts, the main thread can print?  If either thread starts alone, it can progress without contention.

Comment: Oh -- one of them starts out true!  How unexpected.  Hmm, will have to think on what that does.  Maybe nothing important.

Comment: Have `second` thread run to completion while `first` thread never starts.  Then have main thread run until join.  Now have `first` thread run.  Or have `first` run after second to completion.  I see more than one possible string output, so I am uncertain why it should be one particular one.

Comment: The `first` thread and `main` should join after `second`, that's what I think will get us desired output